# Multiple upload paperclip error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

I m trying to implement multiple upload images for my app with paperclip like  [this link](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

Actually simple upload work, but if I try to implement an array I have an error.

> undefined method `create' for Paperclip::Attachment:0x007f33ecb3bd30

campings_controller.rb

```
def create

        @camping = Camping.new((camping_params).merge(:user_id => current_user.id))

      respond_to do |format|
        if @camping.save
          format.html { redirect_to @camping, notice: 'Camping was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @camping }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @camping.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def update
    @camping = Camping.find(params[:id])
     if params[:image]
        params[:image].each do |image|
          @camping.create(image: image)
        end
      end
      end
```

_edit.html.erb

```
<%= file_field_tag "image[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

camping.rb

```
has_attached_file :image, default_url: "/images/missing.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate model.

In the link you sent, you have Rails models Gallery and Picture (with gallery has_many pictures) - Looking at the exception, you have one Camping and that has one file field that's holding the picture. The file field can only hold a reference to one file, so you'll need to create a model to track each instance (or a separate column for each picture).

You want to create a model called "CampingPicture", set the paperclip image on the camping picture, set Camping has_many :camping_pictures and CampingPictures belongs_to :camping, and then do

```
 params[:image].each do |image|
   @camping.camping_pictures.create(image: image)
 end
```